# SSH "No supported authentication methods available"

Tags: debian, ssh, raspbian

I was working remotely on my Raspberry and Putty lost the session. 
When I tried to reconnect throws me an error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ19B.jpg
"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,keyboard-interactive)"

I googled that and allways the problem is for people who fails their first ssh connection, but not when you are working on it without changing anything of ssh connections. I was editing fstab.

Anyone has an idea what happened and how can I fix it if I do not have physical access to the pc?

Comment: Have the ssh keys been changed on the Pi?

Comment: I have not changed anything. I was working on fstab (automating mounts)

Comment: It seems you messed up at least the mount of `/home`

Comment: How can I ruin it if it still ask me for user and password? When I introduce the user it returns the error.

Comment: I can login at the same local network, but if I type the external IP in puty returns the error just after introducing the username.